# setState inside setInterval not behaving as expected

Tags: reactjs

I want a simple counter to update the state every second (or whatever). I'm using `setInterval` because I don't know how else to do it. I want the state change to be reflected in the markup and change on the screen.

Currently the idea works without `setState`, but as soon as `setState` is added values become undefined, values jump incorrectly, and infinite loops occur.

```
 this.state = {
    numberLine: {
    1: {
      end: 42
       }  
      }
    }
```

I change the value and then reassign the entire value of the object

```
  counter(start) {
    const that = this
    const copy = _.cloneDeep(this.state.numberLine)
    function timer() {
       copy['1'].end = start
       that.setState({
           numberLine: copy
        })
      }
       let counter = setInterval(timer, 1000)
      }


   renderCustomMarkUp(num) {
    this.counter(num)
     return (
       <span>
          {this.state.numberLine['1'].end}
        </span>
         )
       }


     // call in render
       {this.renderCustomMarkUp(this.state.numberLine['1'].end)}
```

I'd expect the value to update by one each section here. Then when printing the state expect to see the value increase. Instead, I get either gibberish like the same number with occasional jumps, or it freezes. Check [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/drumgod/hr4j02bp/42/) out. Make sure to let the timer get to at least 55-60 before leaving.

It doesn't seem this `setInterval` thing is the correct approach. How should I fix it?

Comment: Here, I fixed things up for you: https://jsfiddle.net/4hkoy6c7/6/

Comment: The main issue you were running into was that you were calling your `counter` method on every render and therefore you were setting new `setInterval`s on every render.

Comment: Instead, you should set your interval once, on component mount.

Comment: So this is instead of passing in the variable? The counter just gets it from state each time in your example. Cool and thanks. RE: onMount - in reality I need to run it at a certain time, not on mount. Hopefully it is just a matter of calling it at that time using your logic inside of the function that runs later.

Comment: Also, if I may, I would recommend using Code Sandbox in the future for your React playground since JSFiddle throws some weird syntax errors that aren't relevant. Here's the solution I posted in code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-dawn-kwp1w

Also Code Sandbox will auto-format your code on save (unlike JS Fiddle).

Comment: That's exactly it. You can just access state directly and increment it before setting a new state. No need to use other variables since state is available to you anywhere in your React component 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fixed your demo in a Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-dawn-kwp1w

The issue you were running into was that you were calling `setInterval(timer, 1000)` on every render. So every time you updated state, you were calling `setInterval(timer, 1000)`, which was setting up many timers that would get triggered at 1s intervals.

Instead I've changed your component so that it only calls `setInterval(timer, 1000)` when the component mounts and i'm also using state directly when it comes time to increment the value of your counter.